# Integral $\int{ \frac{1}{\sqrt {1 - e^{2x}} } dx}$

Tags: integration

I need a hint how to start solving this integral:

$$\int{ \frac{1}{\sqrt {1 - e^{2x}} } dx}$$

Comment: Are you aware of the function $\tanh^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Let $\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}=y\implies e^{2x}=1-y^2$

and $$\dfrac{2e^{2x}\ dx}{2\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}=-dy\iff\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}=\dfrac{dy}{y^2-1}$$

Comment: Another way is to set $e^x$  or $e^{2x}=u$

Comment: Why to post two answers? Unifying them is not good?

Comment: @GudsonChou, As the methods are different. Putting multiple independent answers in one often reduces legibility

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}=\dfrac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{e^{-2x}-1}}$$

Set $e^{-x}=\sec\theta$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\int_{x} (1-e^{2x})^{-1/2} = \int_{u := \sin^{-1}e^{2x}} (\cos u)^{-1}\frac{\cos u}{2\sin u} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{u}\frac{1}{\sin u} = \frac{1}{2}\log \bigg| \frac{\cos \sin^{-1} e^{2x}}{e^{2x}} \bigg| + \text{some constant}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative hint...setting $e^{-x}=\cosh\theta$ makes it very straightforward...