# Where is my mistake in the evaluation of $\int\;\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}dx$?

Tags: integration, solution-verification, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate Integral :
$$\int\;\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}dx $$

**My attempt:**

I know that my answer is wrong, but I don't know exactly where the error is. I need help finding out?

$$I = \int\;\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}dx$$
let : $$t＝e^{x}\;\implies\;dt＝e^{x}dx\;\implies\;dt＝tdx\implies\;dx＝\textstyle\frac {dt}{t}$$
And therefore :
$$\implies\;I＝\int\;\frac {1}{\sqrt {1－t^2}}×\frac {1}{t}dt＝\int\frac {1}{t\sqrt {1-t^2}}dt$$
let : $$t＝\cos\theta\;\implies\;dt＝\sin\theta\;d\theta$$
And therefore :
$$\implies\;I＝\int\;\frac {\sin\theta d\theta}{\cos\theta\sqrt {1-\cos^2(\theta)}}＝\int\;\frac {－d\theta}{\cos\theta}\\~\\＝-\ln\frac {1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}＝\ln\frac {\cos\theta}{1＋\sin\theta}＋c$$

> $$using : \sin(\cos^{-1}(t))＝\sqrt {1－t^2}$$

$$\implies\;I＝\ln\frac {\cos(\cos^{-1}(t))}{1＋\sin(\cos^{-1}(t))}＝\ln\frac t{1＋\sqrt {1－t^2}}\\~\\I＝\ln\frac {e^x}{1＋\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}＋C$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integral $\int{ \frac{1}{\sqrt {1 - e^{2x}} } dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414559/integral-int-frac1-sqrt-1-e2x-dx)

Comment: No, I'm looking for the error I made in the solution

Comment: Why do you think your solution might be wrong? Do you have a "correct" one to compare it to? (Given the presence of $\ln$, it's possible your solution doesn't match the prescribed one because it differs by a constant.)

Comment: OP, I agree with your comment, so I retracted my vote to close as a duplicate, but I can see that someone else voted for such a closing. May be (s)he did not read well your post and comment? And (s)he also missed the "solution-verification" tag? I made things even clearer by changing your title, to correspond better to your body.

Comment: Also evaluated to $$\int\;\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}dx =-\text{sech}^{-1}(e^{x})$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that your integrand is defined only for $x<0.$

Your final result is correct:
$$\begin{align}\left(\ln\frac {e^x}{1＋\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}\right)'&=\frac{1＋\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}{e^x}\left(\frac {e^x}{1＋\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}\right)'
\\&=\frac{1＋\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}{e^x}~~~\frac {e^x(1＋\sqrt {1-e^{2x}})-e^x\frac{-2e^{2x}}{2\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}}{(1＋\sqrt {1-e^{2x}})^2}\\
&=\frac {1＋\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}+\frac{e^{2x}}{\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}}{1＋\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}
\\
&=\frac {\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}+1-e^{2x}+e^{2x}}{\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}(1＋\sqrt {1-e^{2x}})}
\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt {1-e^{2x}}}
\end{align}$$
All your calculations (including $\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$ and your logarithms, which are taken on positive expressions) are also correct, since your two intermediate changes of variable
$$t=e^x,\theta=\cos^{-1}(t),$$
force $\theta$ to be in $(0,\pi/2)$ when $x<0.$

Answer (score 0):

Who says that you answer is incorrect. It's correct dude. :)

We don't take the constant term into consideration when evaluating indefinite integrals. So maybe that's why your answer wasn't matching the prescribed one.

If you're ever confused whether your answer is correct or not then go to this [calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) then enter the integral that you wish to evaluate. When it gets solved, click on the check answer button (it is a green checkmark alongside the answer) and enter your own answer. It will tell you whether your expression and the answer calculated by the calculator are equivalent or not.